# Unexpected token < in JSON at position -core.js:1449

Tags: json, phpmyadmin, ionic3

I'm having trouble in this JSON.

```
> ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0   core.js:1449
>     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
>     at Response.Body.json (http.js:1091)
>     at MapSubscriber.project (register.ts:86)
>     at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:79)
>     at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:93)
>     at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.js:1591)
>     at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
>     at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4751)
>     at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
>     at r.runTask (polyfills.js:3)
```

**register.ts**

```
loader.present().then(() => {
      this.http.post('http://localhost/mobile/register.php', data, options)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(res => {
```

**register.php**

```
?php

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
    }

    // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

        exit(0);
    }

  require "dbconnect.php";

    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
    if (isset($data)) {
        $request = json_decode($data);
        $username = $request->username;
        $emailadd = $request->emailadd;
        $mobile = $request->mobile;
        $pass = $request->pass;        
    }

$username = stripslashes($username);
$pass = stripslashes($pass);



$sql = "INSERT INTO master_user (username, emailadd, mobile, pass)
VALUES ('$username', '$emailadd', '$mobile', '$pass')";


if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $response= "Registration successfull";

} else {
   $response= "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $db->error;
}


    echo json_encode( $response);


?>
```

[image]

Comment: As the error says, you are not returning a valid json file. I would assume your register.php renders some html since you have the < character at position 0. The problem is not here but in your php file.

Comment: hi sir i updated the content of my question can your spot the unexpected token?

Comment: View the contents of this POST operation using the Network tools in your browser. I suspect you will find that this string is not JSON.

Comment: @halfer hi sir i have a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58296112/how-to-display-data-from-a-local-json-file-by-clicking-the-button