# How to prevent checkbox from selecting all when setting its variable to true or false?

Tags: angular, ionic3

I made an [accordion list with ionic [v3]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cH33gmOHJMU&t=147s) as you can see in the link video tutorial the select option menu is not in the .html file. The list items in the menu are from .json file as you can see in my .ts file

form.html

```html
    .....
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of child.children" detail-none class="child-item" text-wrap no-lines>
         <ion-label>{{ item.name }} <p style="color: #0077ff;">{{ selected }}</p> </ion-label>
         <ion-checkbox item-end [(ngModel)]="value" (click)="tofix(item)"></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
    .....
```

form.ts

```js
    export class FormPage  implements OnInit{
      data: any[];

      public SelectedItemToFix: string = '';

      @Input('item') item: any;

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
                  public navParams: NavParams, 
                  private http: Http,
                  private toastCtrl: ToastController) {
                    let localData = this.http.get('assets/data/menus.json').map(res => res.json().items);
                      localData.subscribe(data => {
                        this.data = data;
                      });
                      this.title = navParams.get('title');
                      this.subtitle = navParams.get('subtitle');
                  }

      toggleSection(i) {
        this.data[i].open = !this.data[i].open;
      }

      toggleItem(i, j) {
        this.data[i].children[j].open = !this.data[i].children[j].open;
      }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

    value = false;
    public selected: string = '';

        async tofix(item){
          let toast = await this.toastCtrl.create({
            message: `Added item to be fix : ${item.name}`,
            duration: 2000
          }); 
          console.log(this.value);
          this.SelectedItemToFix += `${item.name}`;
          if(this.value == true){
            this.selected = "Item Selected"
          }
          else{
            this.selected = "Cancelled"
          }
          toast.present();
        }
```

[image: cancelled selection][image: when selecting only 1 item]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are ngModel all checkboxes to the same `value`.

To fix it you could use the `open` attribute on your object :`this.data[i].children[j].open`.

Also you can remove `public selected: string = '';` and do it in the item itself, therwise you have the same problem as with the value.

```html
.....
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of child.children" detail-none class="child-item" text-wrap no-lines>
     <ion-label>
          {{ item.name }} 
          <p style="color: #0077ff;">
              {{ item.open ? 'Item Selected' : 'Cancelled'}}
          </p> 
     </ion-label>
     <ion-checkbox item-end [(ngModel)]="item.open" (click)="tofix(item)"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
.....
```

Comment: sir but the cancelled is displayed by default

Comment: Yes because the item is not selected, or do you want alle item to be selected on default? If not, what is your expected behavior?

Comment: Sorry about that sir I will just empty the cancelled string. Maximum respect+ for your sir thank you so much. I'll post next question about the select item redundancy issue.

Comment: @Nobert Bartko https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58435895/how-to-prevent-ion-checkbox-from-selecting-the-same-item-value