# How to align the second div to right when the two divs are displayed in flex?

Tags: ionic3

I want the second div to align at the right to place it in where it should be but is it possible if they're displayed in flex? Help me guys this one gives me headache.

login.html

```
    <div style="display: flex;">
      <div (click)="openPasswordRecovery()" style="color:gray">
        Remember Me
      </div>
      <div style="text-align: right; color:gray">
        Forgot Password?
      </div>              
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `space-between`, the last item always goes to the end:

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: 'space-between'">
```

Learn more about [justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) here

Comment: Dang https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58553369/how-to-customize-date-now-format

Comment: Sorry, I will not investigate and answer that question, I hate Angular to the bone.