# How to customize date.now format?

Tags: angular, ionic3

.ts

```
currentDate = Date.now();
```

.html

```
{{ currentDate | date }}
```

How can I display the time instead of Oct 25, 2019 I want it this way:

> Signed this {{25th}} day of {{October}} {{2019}}?

Anyone there already implemented custom time format?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#custom-format-options

Comment: currentDate | MMMM --> The pipe 'MMMM' could not be found T_T

Comment: I'd recommend reading the docs more carefully. That's **not** how they show passing the additional arguments and is in fact, as the error tells you, an attempt to pass the resulting string from the date pipe to another pipe that doesn't exist.

Comment: I recommend using moment.js library instead

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a custom pipe for your date suffix and take the rest from the angular `date` pipe.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

 @Pipe({ name: 'dateSuffix' })
 export class DateSuffixPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(date: Date): string {
      let day = date.getDay();
      let suffix = 'th';

      if (day == 1 || day == 21 || day == 31) {
        suffix = 'st';
      }
      if (day == 2 || day == 22) {
        suffix = 'nd';
      }
      if (day == 3 || day == 23) {
        suffix = 'rd';
      }

       return suffix;
    } 
 }
```

HTML

```
<div>
    Signed this {{currentDate | date:'dd'}}{{currentDate | dateSuffix}} day of {{currentDate | date:'LLLL yyyy'}}
</div>
```

Don't forget to add your custom pipe to module declarations!

Comment: all the **day === ' '** underlined red says **This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'number' and '" "' have no overlap.**

Answer (score 1):

Full stackblitz with suffix and language support for month =  working demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-how-to-customize)

You can use this pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "customDatePipe",
  pure: true
})
export class CustomDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(date: Date): string {
    if (!date) {
      return;
    }

    const day = date.getDate();
    const monthName = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", { month: "long" })
      .format;
    const longName = monthName(date); // "July"
    const year = date.getFullYear();

    let suffix = "th";

    if (day === 1 || day === 21 || day === 31) {
      suffix = "st";
    }
    if (day === 2 || day === 22) {
      suffix = "nd";
    }
    if (day === 3 || day === 23) {
      suffix = "rd";
    }

       return `Signed this ${day}${suffix} day of ${longName} ${year}`
      }
   }
```

Comment: I don't know how to implement this on my page still gives me "could not be found"

Comment: What is not found?

Comment: The answer works on stackblitz, so it solved your problem, if you don't know how to implement it in your project then it is up to you. But the answer is correct! :D

Comment: Add pipe to declarations array?

Comment: Unexpected value 'DecoratorFactory' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

Comment: Can you send the code of your custom pipe file?

You should have @Pipe({
  name: "customDatePipe",
  pure: true
})

Comment: what version of angular that can generate .pipe file? mine is @angular/core": "5.2.11",

Comment: I am using angular 8, but you can try this command in v5 as well,
ng generate pipe [name] = generates a pipe

Comment: $ ng generate pipe currentDate
The generate command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.

Comment: But when I ng --version I got Angular CLI: 8.3.5
Node: 12.7.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.11

Comment: Why is this happening sir?

Comment: @MjSaijem You have to run that command in directory of your angular app, so steps are:
1. run cd pathToYourDirectory,
2. run ng generate pipe currentDate

Comment: I know. I run it in my project as you can see in my previous reply I was able to see the angular version of my project.