# The generate command requires to be run in an Angular project?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm wondering why I am getting this kind of message whenever I try to add a component in my angular project although I have Angular CLI installed in my project.

[image][image]
[image][image]

Comment: there should be some mistake in your project path

Comment: Did you create this project with the Angular CLI? I didn't see the angular.json file. It is required If you want to use the CLI command, start with `ng`

Comment: Yes sir, as you can see in the first image I was able to run the ng --version in my ionic project.

Comment: But `ng --version` is a global command that works outside of a project. The question is which ionic version are you using?

Comment: @NorbertBartko I update my question sir with ionic info

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know does ionic 3 dont create a `angular.json`, and that's what angular i looking for when you want to create for example a `pipe`.

When you want to create a `pipe` in ionic 3 just run `ionic g pipe myPipe`.

When you upgrade to ionic 4+ it will create a `angular.json` like a normal angular project would do.
See here ("@ionic/angular": "^4.7.1")

[image]

Then you can run all kind of `ng` command your used to from angular.